# Magento 2 get dimensions of products in order event

Tags: magento2, attributes, event-observer, products

I'm trying to get the dimensions(length,width and height) and weight of all products in an order.

The event that I'm using is `checkout_submit_all_after`.

In observer I have this code.

```
$order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
$orderItems = $order->getAllItems();
    $dimensions = array();
    $weight = 0;
    foreach ($orderItems as $item) {
          $dimensions[]=array('weigth'=>$item->getData('weight'),'length'=>$item->getData('ts_dimensions_length'),'width'=>$item->getData('ts_dimensions_width'),'height'=>$item->getData('ts_dimensions_height'));
           $weight += ($item->getData('weight') * $item->getQty());
           $this->logger->info("weight: ".$weight);
     }

     $encodedData =  $this->_jsonHelper->jsonEncode($dimensions);
     $this->logger->info("Dimensiones: ".$encodedData);
```

When I print weight, I'm getting 0, I found that it takes the value of the variable initialized and never gets the total weight of all products.

And when I print the array in json form, I get this:

```
Dimensiones: [{"weigth":"2.0000","length":null,"width":null,"height":null}]
```

The product weight is correct, but it's just printing one product, even if there are more than one product in cart.
The dimensions are always null, I never get the actual values of the dimensions.
What am I doing wrong?

Greetings!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following way:

```
/** @var \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order */
$order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
$orderItems = $order->getAllItems();
$dimensions = [];
$weight = 0;
foreach ($orderItems as $item) {
    $product = $item->getProduct();
    $dimensions[] = [
        'weigth' => $product->getData('weight'),
        'length' => $product->getData('ts_dimensions_length'),
        'width' => $product->getData('ts_dimensions_width'),
        'height' => $product->getData('ts_dimensions_height')
    ];
    $weight += ($product->getData('weight') * $item->getQty());
}
```

Comment: Hello, Thank you! I'm getting the dimensions now, but $weight is still 0 when I print it out of the foreach.